# How is static member variable distributed to workers in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, serializable

```
public class MapMatchingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...

        MapMatching mapMatching = new MapMatching(hopper, opts);

        JavaRDD<String> matchedTraces = traceData.map(
                new Function<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(String s) throws Exception {
                        return singleTraceMatch(getTraceFromString(s), mapMatching));
                    }
                }
        );
        }
    }
```

when I instantiate the `mapMatching` instance in the `main()` method, I will get the error that

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

```
public class MapMatchingMain {

    private static MapMatching mapMatching = new MapMatching();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        JavaRDD<String> matchedTraces = traceData.map(
                new Function<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(String s) throws Exception {
                        return singleTraceMatch(getTraceFromString(s));
                    }
                }
        );
        }
    }
```

If I instantiate the `mapMatching` instance as a static member variable of class `MapMatchingMain`, it has no problem.

I have read some answers said that the static field value was not serialized. So how is it distributed to each worker in spark?

Comment: Each worker has its own instance. When it loads the class the static var is created locally on each JVM.

Comment: @Hitobat Thanks. In my situation, creating the instance needs to load a file in the driver. If it is created locally on each worker,  how does it make it? And this looks like `broadcast`. What is the main difference? Do they have the same efficiency?

Comment: This only works for static vars that are hard-coded with some specific values. If you're loading dynamic data on the driver then you need to use `broadcast`. Also anthing you intend to broadcast must be serializable.